# What is org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler package for?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-jdt

I was profiling a java based web application(InsecureWebApp from OWASP) and came across methods from org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler package. I googled it to know for what purpose they are used.. I looked here (http://www.cs.utep.edu/cheon/download/jml4c/javadocs/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/package-summary.html) but could not understand what is its purpose in general.

Can somebody please help me out here ?

Thanks

Comment: These are internal packages within the Eclipse compiler. Some platforms (e.g. [Tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt)) embed the JDT plugin for things like compiling JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess thats Eclipse Java compiler.

Eclipse don't use the standard compiler, but have ther own that compiles your code incrementally while typing.